# Noise removal with morphological operations

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have an image consisting of lines and dots of the same width. Can I remove all dots using only morphological operations?

Comment: The answer is probably “yes”. But I can’t write an answer because I don’t know what your image looks like. Please be more specific, include at least an example image. Also, if you are looking for something other than a yes/no answer, don’t ask a yes/no question. You should read  [ask].

Answer (score 0):

As you are not providing more information on your problem i can only suggest you take a look at erosion;
 make up your mind about what a kernel has to look like to remove the noise in your image.